# WPF ItemsControl not refreshing

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, itemscontrol

I'm working on a WPF project. I have a class like this:

```
public class Field
{
    public ReservationDTO reservation { get; set; }

    public DelegateCommand FieldChangeCommand { get; set; }

    public bool Available { get; set; }
}
```

And I have a collection of it

```
public ObservableCollection<Field> Fields { get; set; }
```

My view looks like this

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Fields}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <UniformGrid
                Columns="{Binding Columns}"
                Rows="{Binding Rows}"
                />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Button Command="{Binding FieldChangeCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding}" Content="{Binding reservation.Statusz}" FontSize="5" IsEnabled="{Binding Available}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
```

This works perfectly for the first time, when it loads. But later on I might have some values of Fields changed. For example: (part of the viewmodel code)

```
Fields[SelectedIndex].reservation.Statusz = "Sold";
Fields[SelectedIndex].Available = false;
OnPropertyChanged("Fields");
OnPropertyChanged("Available");
```

Is sure that Fields get updated after this, because other elements on the view (like textboxes) refresh. But the buttongrid on the view doesn't update with the new values of Fields.

Can somebody please tell me why, and how to solve this problem?

Comment: Are you implement INotifyPropertyChanged in your ReservationDTO class. If not then the UI won't be receiving notifications that your Statusz property has changed.

Comment: @Bijington I have ViewModelBase like this.

public abstract class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;


        protected ViewModelBase() { }

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = null)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }

Comment: @Bijington if I make my Field class derived from ViewModelBase is that enough? Because I'm not sure if I can modify ReservationDTO class like that.

Comment: You should write properties like `private bool_available; public bool Available { get { return _available; } set { _available = value; OnPropertyChanged("Available"); } }`

Comment: @grpzeneszerzo I have added an answer that I believe will cover what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Content of your button is bound to the Statusz property on your ReservationDTO class which means that will need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged in order for the Buttons content to change to "Sold". It is understandable you wouldn't want it on your DTO class.

Also the calls to OnPropertyChanged look wrong to me (I am assuming that your ViewModel has the Fields property on it and is the class that inherits from ViewModelBase?

You need to do something like the following (Please note I haven't added any null reference checks for your _reservation field):

```
public class Field : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool _available;
    private ReservationDTO _reservation;

    public string Statusz
    {
        get
        {
            return _reservation.Statusz;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_reservation.Statusz != value)
            {
                _reservation.Statusz = value;

                OnPropertyChanged("Available");
            }
        }
    }

    public DelegateCommand FieldChangeCommand { get; set; }

    public bool Available
    {
        get
        {
            return _available;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_available != value)
            {
                _available = value;

                OnPropertyChanged("Available");
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        var localHandler = this.PropertyChanged;

        if (localHandler != null)
        {
            localHandler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));       
        }
    }
}
```

And then change your buttons binding to:

```
<Button Command="{Binding FieldChangeCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding}" Content="{Binding Statusz}" FontSize="5" IsEnabled="{Binding Available}"/>
```

Comment: This looks very nice, and I understand the reason. Though I have a problem, that this.PropertyChanged gives an error (does not contain a definition). Could you tell how to solve this problem? Maybe I should move my Field class out the viewmodel?
class ReservationViewModel : ViewModelBase

Comment: Sorry I missed the property changed event handler declaration I have added it into my answer. You can just add the following to your Field class: public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;